# iOS MapKit Performance Issue Using Satellite Tiles

Tags: ios, performance, mkmapview, mapkit, gpu

I have an iOS 8 app that uses MapKit. I recently discovered a performance problem with the app when running a video decompression in addition to displaying a map. The app was unable to keep up with the flow of incoming data when using the satellite view tile set. However, this problem vanished the moment I swapped to the default MapKit tile set. The app is not CPU bottlenecked when the problem is occurring. It makes sense to me that the default (vector) map tile set is easier to display, but I am confused about why the issue is happening in the first place.

The problem seems strange to me because there is no movement or manipulation of the map when the problem is occurring. I would understand the issue better if it happened when manipulating the map in addition to rendering video to the screen, but the problem exists even with no user input. I am constrained in analyzing the system because we use a hardware accessory, so some Instruments are not available over wireless performance analysis. I am not using a high number of annotations, overlays, or other objects. We have a few custom annotations and overlays in use. There are existing apps that do this exact combination of decoding and maps, without the performance problem, so I suspect it's a configuration issue.

Are there certain attributes on the MKMapView that I can set to improve performance? I am at a loss as to what to investigate further since I cannot make the problem happen with the GPU Instrument active and the CPU doesn't appear to be the constraint.

Comment: Sounds tricky. If you have a difficult issue that needs troubleshooting (especially since you're using a hardware accessory) then you should think about using one of your Technical Support Incidents with Apple. You get 2 incidents per year with your developer membership.